# How to Install GTK-2 on Linux

Tags: rhel

I tried installing "libgtk2.0-dev" with below command. But it failed with

```
yum install libgtk2.0-dev
Error "No package libgtk2.0-dev available"
```

There are many posts related to this issue but none works out as no post covered this issue in entirety

example: One Post recommended to follow below steps. I tried it but of no avail

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"  
yum install gtk+-devel gtk2-devel
```

I am using "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga)".

Can someone help with steps to install this library ( in plain english as I have never installed one )

Comment: As I have no access to a RHEL 5.x machine, what does `yum search gtk2` return?

Comment: @schaiba: Below is output when I ran yum search gtk2                            Loaded plugins: dkms-build-requires, priorities, security
al-acc       | 1.9 kB     00:00     
al-amazon    |  951 B     00:00     
al-main      | 2.1 kB     00:00     
al-updates   | 2.1 kB     00:00     
slc6-devtoolset   | 2.6 kB     00:00     
testing-devtools-2-centos-2012.03   |  951 B     00:00     
=====Matched: gtk2 =====
pygobject2-devel.x86_64 : Development files for building add-on libraries

Comment: OK. What does `yum repolist` say? Also, please try to format the output for easier reading.

Comment: @schaiba:                                                                                                    Loaded plugins: dkms-build-requires, priorities, security\n
`repo id                 repo name\n              
al-acc                   2012.03 x86_64 ACC 
al-amazon             x86_64 Amazon    
al-main                  2012.03 x86_64 Server 
al-updates             2012.03 x86_64 Updates
slc6-devtoolset       Scientific Linux CERN 6 (SLC6) - Devtoolset addons 
testing-devtools-2-centos-2012.03   testing 2 devtools for CentOS 2012.03` 
repolist: 5,781

Comment: For starters why do you have Scientific Linux 6 repos on a RHEL 5 system?  Second, I believe you have some default repos missing, so you should start looking into that.

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo yum install make automake gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel 
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" "Development Libraries"
```